# Identifying dates from datespan for multiple entries

Tags: mysql, sql, loops, date, calendar

I need your guidance in regard to a query I am trying to write, but hitting a wall on.  I am working on a project for a scheduling system.  The scheduling system has in it a dates calendar table, a yearsemester table with datespans, a courses table with courses assigned to yearsemesters, and a components table with the course components (days of week & times) listed.

I need to write a query that identifies every day of the week within a given datesspan (parameters), from a web form, where a class takes place.

**These tables approximately look like the example below:**

**(Dates) Calendar Table:**

| Date | DayofWeek |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | Friday |
| 2021-01-02 | Saturday |
| 2021-01-03 | Sunday |

.... On and on for like 20 years worth of dates

**(YearSemester) table:**

| ID | Year | Semster | Start Date | End Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021 | Spring | 2021-01-04 | 2021-05-01 |
| 2 | 2021 | Summer | 2021-06-01 | 2021-08-15 |
| 3 | 2021 | Fall | 2021-08-15 | 2021-12-30 |

**(CoursesSchedule) table:**

| ID | YearSemesterID | CourseID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | CTI120 |
| 2 | 1 | DBA110 |
| 3 | 1 | DBA225 |

**(ComponentSchedule) table:**

| ID | CourseScheduleID | Component | DayofWeek | Start Time | End Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Class | Monday | 8:00 AM | 10:00 AM |
| 2 | 1 | lab | Monday | 11:00 AM | 11:50 AM |
| 3 | 1 | Class | Wednesday | 8:00 AM | 10:00 AM |
| 4 | 1 | Lab | Wednesday | 11:00 AM | 11:50 AM |
| 5 | 2 | Class | Tuesday | 5:00 PM | 9:00 PM |
| 6 | 2 | Class | Thursday | 5:00 PM | 9:00 PM |
| 7 | 3 | Class | Monday | 1:00 PM | 3:00 PM |
| 8 | 3 | Class | Friday | 1:00 PM | 3:00 PM |

I need to find a way using either the calendars table, or some other method, to generate a result set like the following when given start and end dates as parameters from a web form

**INTENDED QUERY OUTPUT**

| YEAR | SEMESTER | COURSE | COMPONENT | DATE | Start Time | End Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | SPRING | CTI110 | CLASS | 2021-01-04 | 8:00 AM | 10:00 AM |
| 2021 | SPRING | CTI110 | LAB | 2021-01-04 | 8:00 AM | 10:00 AM |
| 2021 | SPRING | DBA225 | CLASS | 2021-01-04 | 1:00 PM | 3:00 PM |
| 2021 | SPRING | DBA110 | CLASS | 2021-01-05 | 5:00 PM | 9:00 PM |
| 2021 | SPRING | CTI110 | CLASS | 2021-01-06 | 8:00 AM | 10:00 AM |
| 2021 | SPRING | CTI110 | LAB | 2021-01-06 | 8:00 AM | 10:00 AM |

... And so on and so forth to the end of the date span.  This is to be displayed on the webpage, and used in a calendar view eventually, with some formatting of course.

I can't figure out how to generate the individual dates of occurrence by referencing the semester's date span against the course's component days of the week.  Should this be a loop?

Any advice, or guidance, if you have a good guide on a topic such as this, would be greatly appreciated!!  I haven't been able to find anything super helpful so far.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @Strawberry, MySQL in XAMPP through PHPMYADMIN.  I think it is version 8.  I got the tables needed (shown above) added into a singular wide view.  I just need to figure out how I can run through a provided datespan and identify the individual dates in which the courses apply.